Access HTML <style> tag rules
My question is if there is a way to access the content of HTML <style> element from jQuery.
<style>
.calendarNavbarLink {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.today {
    background-color: lawngreen;
}

.weekend {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}
</style>

For example: I would access the value of the property background-color of the rule .weekend. Is it possible do this from jQuery?

What have you tried? What's the actual issue that you're facing?

How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?... Get CSS rules into javascript variable... etc.  Have you made any attempt?

Step 1:
By using a couple of CSSOM (CSS Object Model) properties, you can query your stylesheet and build an easy-to-search array of selectors and style rules:


// GET ALL STYLESHEETS
let styleSheetCount = document.styleSheets.length;

// GET LAST STYLESHEET
let lastStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[(styleSheetCount - 1)];

// CONVERT STYLESHEET TO OBJECT
const convertStylesheetToObject = (stylesheet) => {
  
  // CREATE AND POPULATE STYLE ARRAY
  let styleArray = [];
  [...stylesheet.cssRules].forEach((cssRule) => styleArray.push(cssRule.cssText));

  styleArray = styleArray.map((style) => ({
    'selectors': style.split('{')[0].split(',').map((selector) => selector.trim()),
    'styles': style.split('{')[1].replace('}', '').trim()
  }));

  styleArray.forEach((style) => style.styles = style.styles.split(';'));
  
  styleArray.forEach((style, s) => {
    let stylesValue = {};
    styleArray[s].styles.forEach((styleDeclaration) => {
      if (styleDeclaration !== '') {
        stylesValue[styleDeclaration.split(':')[0].trim()] = styleDeclaration.split(':')[1].trim();
      }
    });
    styleArray[s].styles = stylesValue;
  });
  
  return styleArray;
}  

console.log(convertStylesheetToObject(lastStyleSheet));
<style>
.calendarNavbarLink {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.today {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.weekend {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
</style>



Having done this, if you now run:
convertStylesheetToObject(lastStyleSheet)

you will get the following array:
[
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".calendarNavbarLink"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "margin-left": "20px"
    }
  },
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".today"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "background-color": "lawngreen"
    }
  },
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".weekend"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "background-color": "lightsalmon"
    }
  }
]

Step 2:
You now have an array you can parse with a helper function.
E.g. If you want to know

[...] the value of the property background-color of the rule .weekend.

you can run:
getStyleValue('.weekend', 'background-color', styleArray)

which returns the following result:


const getStyleValue = (selector, property, styleArray) => {
  
  let styleValue = 'No value found.';
  
  const selectorFilter = styleArray.filter((element) => element.selectors.includes(selector));
  
  if (selectorFilter.length > 0) {
    const propertyFilter = selectorFilter.filter((element) => Object.keys(element.styles).includes(property));
    if (propertyFilter.length > 0) {
      styleValue = propertyFilter.reverse()[0].styles[property];
    }
  }
  
  return styleValue;
}

let styleArray = [
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".calendarNavbarLink"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "margin-left": "20px"
    }
  },
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".today"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "background-color": "lawngreen"
    }
  },
  {
    "selectors": [
      ".weekend"
    ],
    "styles": {
      "background-color": "lightsalmon"
    }
  }
];

console.log(getStyleValue('.weekend', 'background-color', styleArray));




Just inject a pseudo element in the body,assign the desired css rulesand analyze its properties.


$(document).ready(function() {
  var $weekend = $("<div></div>").addClass("weekend");
  $weekend.appendTo("body");
  console.log($weekend.css("background-color"));
  $weekend.remove();
});
.calendarNavbarLink {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.today {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.weekend {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



